# No games work at all

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, steam

So far I have tried downloading Steam and even Tux Racer, and nothing will run. It seems like it's a driver issue. I ran `lspci -v` in the terminal, and this is what popped up for my graphics card:

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4100] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff80
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 9000 [size=256]
    Memory at cfdf0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at cfe00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the free radeon-driver for your graphics, which has a bad 3d performance, therefor the games are not running, you need to install the fglrx-driver to play 3d-games.
Take a look at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI